# Rust: Could not fin 'Win32' in 'windows'

Tags: windows, rust

I was just trying to use the windows crate, but I can't even import Win32. I tried searching online but I haven't found anything.

This is my code:

```
use windows::Win32::*;

fn main() {
}
```

This is the Cargo.toml file:

```
[package]
name = "windows_test_1"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
windows = "0.51.1"
```

Answer (score 2):

The `windows` crate is heavily feature-guarded, to save compilation time. You need to enable the `Win32` feature, or any feature that includes it (e.g. `Win32_Foundation`).

Comment: I think I got it working by adding some stuff to cargo.toml so indeed you need to manually specifiy which features you want. Thank you :)